# Issue in SOAP UI with SQL using Grovvy Script, the working code stopped working

Tags: sql, groovy, soapui

I am hitting DB2 database using grovvy scripts in SOAPUI, the below code was working fine for me for sometime.
However suddenly its not working and I am stuck and unable to find a solution

The query:`SELECT Column_ID FROM Table_Name where Column_TIMESTAMP > '2016-10-26 05:37:22'`

Below is the code

```
def sqlQueryPopID = "SELECT Column_ID FROM Table_Name where Column_TIMESTAMP>'2016-10-26 05:37:22'"

def popID 

**// The code is not entering in the below loop, however was working fine a day back, not sure what happened**

sqlITOD.query(sqlQueryPopID) {resultSet ->
    while (resultSet.next()){
        popID = resultSet.getString(1)
        log.info("Popultauin ID is:"+popID)
    }
}//end of result set

log.info("The Sql Query:"+sqlITOD.query(sqlQueryPopID) )//This line is giving below Error
```

ERROR:

```
Wed Oct 26 05:37:58 EDT 2016:INFO:groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.sql.Sql.query() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [SELECT Column_ID FROM Table_Name where Column_TIMESTAMP>'2016-10-26 05:37:22']
Possible solutions: query(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), query(groovy.lang.GString, groovy.lang.Closure), query(java.lang.String, java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), query(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, groovy.lang.Closure), query(java.util.Map, java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), every()
```

Please help me what went wrong as the current code was working fine, somehow it stopped working

Comment: try sqlITOD.query(sqlQueryPopID, {resultSet ->

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the method is [`Sql.query(groovy.lang.GString,groovy.lang.Closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#query(groovy.lang.GString,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).

So this in your code `log.info("The Sql Query:"+sqlITOD.query(sqlQueryPopID) )` cannot work. Since there is no `query(String)` method in `Sql`.

The rest of your code seems correct; I think that the problem is with your data, in your query you're filtering based on `where Column_TIMESTAMP > '2016-10-26 05:37:22'` so probably the thing is that you don't have any result in the DB which match this criteria.

By the way there is a more groovy way to do the same using [`eachRow`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#eachRow(groovy.lang.GString,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) instead:

```
sqlITOD.eachRow(sqlQueryPopID){ row ->
    log.info("Popultauin ID is: ${row.id}")
}
```

Comment: I tired both the ways, however still not working for me, the code I shared was working for me a day prior.

Comment: @MradulKapoor sorry, I totally misread your question... now I think that the answer is more accurate

Comment: @albcliff: The database has records ( I checked that manually), also the code in not getting inside the resultset loop, however its was working fine till yesterday and I was able to get the details

Comment: @MradulKapoor strange... can you try anyway 
`sql.firstRow("select count(*) as count from FROM Table_Name where Column_TIMESTAMP > '2016-10-26 05:37:22'").count`?

Comment: I tried that as well, its giving me null when I do from soap UI, however works fine when I check manually, its strange and blocker for me

Comment: @MradulKapoor it's strange, what is null from soapui? the result from `sql.firstRow("select count(*) as count from FROM Table_Name where Column_TIMESTAMP > '2016-10-26 05:37:22'")` or when you do `.count` on this object?. In soapui works perfectly for me.